# Choosing Toolbox Items loading super slow/stuck

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, devexpress

I just added the Extended WPF Toolkit Nuget package for my application and whenever I try to add those controls to my designer toolbox, I get stuck loading these DevExpress components. I do have several versions of DevExpress installed on my machine but this loading time is so slow that something is definitely not right. Any ideas on what is going on? Any way to speed this up?

[image]